# Find MySQL queries alternatives to one using UNION - in order to compare their speeds

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a query that selects rows from `topics` table, based on a phrase provided by the user (e.g. "ge"). Every user has a list of topics they follow. I order the results by `priority` column (as an alias):

- Priority 4 - exact match, phrase is in the list of user-followed
  topics
- Priority 3 - partial match, phrase is in the list of user-followed
  topics
- Priority 2 - partial match, topics that start with the phrase
- Priority 1 - partial match, phrase is a substring of a topic name

The query I have uses `UNION`:

```
SELECT id, name, 4 as priority FROM `topics`
WHERE id IN(17, 18, 19, 20, 21) AND name LIKE 'ge'

UNION

SELECT id, name, 3 as priority FROM `topics`
WHERE id IN(17, 18, 19, 20, 21) AND name LIKE '%ge%'

UNION

SELECT id, name, 2 as priority FROM `topics`
WHERE name LIKE 'ge%'

UNION

SELECT id, name, 1 as priority FROM `topics`
WHERE name LIKE '%ge%'

ORDER BY priority DESC
```

The query works fine - it gets the matching results and orders them by `priority`, from highest to lowest.

**What I need is to come up with alternative query/queries that achieve the same goal, to compare their speed for 100 000 records.**

What would be a good alternative to the query above? Should I focus on subqueries? Joins? I would like to end up with most efficient one.

Comment: `FULLTEXT` searching may help, but not on two-letter words. `UNION ALL`  is faster than `UNION` because it doesn't try to eliminate dups. A compound index on `(id,name)`and another on `(name, id)` may help if the table has lots of other columns in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the

```
WHERE name LIKE 'ge%'
```

and similar alternatives with

```
WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST('ge*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Answer (score 0):

A partial speedup is to CREATE a TEMPORARY TABLE with all the rows WHERE NAME LIKE '%ge%', then run the UNION on that table.  The temp table will (hopefully) be a lot smaller, hence faster.

Don't hold your breath; this idea may not be all that great.